# Dishwasher Doesn't Complete Cycle

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

As of last night, without any warning, our dishwasher (Bosch Ascenta) no longer operates correctly. The short version is that it will power on, but when a cycle is started, you hear something trying to spin up and get cut short two or three times. It then continues, water circulates and sloshes around and it sounds like it's working, but after five or ten minutes it shuts down. When opened, it says "Complete," but the dishes aren't washed and the detergent tray has not been opened.

I've Googled/YouTubed this extensively but haven't found any hints as to what the problem is, so I'm not even sure where I'd start with a repair. A repair guy I talked to who doesn't service our town listened to the symptoms and didn't have an obvious candidate.

I've pulled the filter, cleaned it, and felt around for any openings jammed up with anything but no joy.

I've done a soft reset with the keys and a hard reset with the breaker, still no joy.

Most Bosch dishwashers have a diagnostic cycle you can put them through to pinpoint problems. Near as I can determine, mine does not.

We can't get anyone out to repair it, so we looked into buying a new one but everyone is sold out into September thanks to the outbreak.

So while it's a long shot, I figured I'd drop a post in here in case anyone had any ideas because I'm fresh out and looking at two months with no washing machine.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Why can't  you  get someone to repair it?  Too old a model?  you live in the boonies?    FWIW in my experience Bosch machines are fantastic when working, but the control boards die a lot; my guess is you'll need a new board.

Comment: Repair isn't an option because the appliance shops will only service gear they retailed, and the only independent repairman in town retired a month ago.